# Attach/ Display same Fieldset for every checkbox option

Tags: 7, entities

how do I re-use a fieldset/group for each checkbox option of a List field. [Please see the form mock-up attached]

"Samples collected" is a List(check boxes) field with few options (one, two, three, etc..)

I want to attach a fieldset for each checkbox option, and display each fieldset only when its checkbox is ticked. The fields in the fieldset are same for every options.

What is the best way of achieving this?

I have tried Inline entity ref field instead of fieldset, but empty entities are created even for those check-boxes not checked.

[image]

Comment: Did u try conditional fields module ??

Comment: hi, yes I have got conditional fields module enabled. But I am unsure how to add/attach fieldsets to each checkbox option. Any ideas on that?

Comment: With Inline_Entity_Ref-Single_Value, everything works well, except that empty entities are created for the checkboxes that aren't ticked. How to resolve this?